# How do you convert a parent-child (adjacency) table to a nested set using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, nested-sets, adjacency-list

I've spent the last few hours trying to find the solution to this question online.  I've found plenty of examples on how to convert from nested set to adjacency... but few that go the other way around.  The examples I have found either don't work or use MySQL procedures.  Unfortunately, I can't use procedures for this project.  I need a pure PHP solution.

I have a table that uses the adjacency model below:

```
id          parent_id         category
1           0                 Books
2           0                 CD's
3           0                 Magazines
4           1                 Books/Hardcover
5           1                 Books/Large Format
6           3                 Magazines/Vintage
```

And I would like to convert it to a Nested Set table below:

```
id    left    right          category
0     1       14             Root Node
1     2       7              Books
4     3       4              Books/Hardcover
5     5       6              Books/Large Format
2     8       9              CD's
3     10      13             Magazines
6     11      12             Magazines/Vintage
```

Here is an image of what I need:

[image: Nested Tree Chart]

I have a function, based on the pseudo code from this forum post (http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=320444) but it doesn't work.  I get multiple rows that have the same value for left.  This should not happen.

```
<?php

/**

--
-- Table structure for table `adjacent_table`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adjacent_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `father_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `adjacent_table`
--

INSERT INTO `adjacent_table` (`id`, `father_id`, `category`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'ROOT'),
(2, 1, 'Books'),
(3, 1, 'CD''s'),
(4, 1, 'Magazines'),
(5, 2, 'Hard Cover'),
(6, 2, 'Large Format'),
(7, 4, 'Vintage');

--
-- Table structure for table `nested_table`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nested_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lft` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rgt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

*/

    mysql_connect('localhost','USER','PASSWORD') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('DATABASE') or die(mysql_error());
    adjacent_to_nested(0);

    /**
     * adjacent_to_nested
     *
     * Reads a "adjacent model" table and converts it to a "Nested Set" table.
     * @param   integer     $i_id           Should be the id of the "root node" in the adjacent table;
     * @param   integer     $i_left         Should only be used on recursive calls.  Holds the current value for lft
     */
    function adjacent_to_nested($i_id, $i_left = 0)
    {

        // the right value of this node is the left value + 1
        $i_right = $i_left + 1;

        // get all children of this node
        $a_children = get_source_children($i_id);
        foreach  ($a_children as $a)
        {

            // recursive execution of this function for each child of this node
            // $i_right is the current right value, which is incremented by the 
            // import_from_dc_link_category method
            $i_right = adjacent_to_nested($a['id'], $i_right);

            // insert stuff into the our new "Nested Sets" table
            $s_query = "
                INSERT INTO `nested_table` (`id`, `lft`, `rgt`, `category`) 
                VALUES(
                    NULL, 
                    '".$i_left."',
                    '".$i_right."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($a['category'])."'
                )
            ";
            if (!mysql_query($s_query))
            {
                echo "<pre>$s_query</pre>\n";
                throw new Exception(mysql_error());  
            }
            echo "<p>$s_query</p>\n";

            // get the newly created row id
            $i_new_nested_id = mysql_insert_id();

        }

        return $i_right + 1;
    }



    /**
     * get_source_children
     *
     * Examines the "adjacent" table and finds all the immediate children of a node
     * @param   integer     $i_id           The unique id for a node in the adjacent_table table
     * @return  array                       Returns an array of results or an empty array if no results.
     */
    function get_source_children($i_id)
    {


        $a_return = array();
        $s_query = "SELECT * FROM `adjacent_table` WHERE `father_id` = '".$i_id."'";
        if (!$i_result = mysql_query($s_query))
        {
            echo "<pre>$s_query</pre>\n";
            throw new Exception(mysql_error());  
        }
        if (mysql_num_rows($i_result) > 0)
        {
            while($a = mysql_fetch_assoc($i_result))
            {
                $a_return[] = $a;
            }
        }

        return $a_return;
    }

?>
```

This is the output of the above script.

> INSERT INTO `nested_table` (`id`,
>   `lft`, `rgt`, `category`) VALUES(
>   NULL, '2', '5', 'Hard Cover' )
>
> INSERT INTO `nested_table` (`id`,
>   `lft`, `rgt`, `category`) VALUES(
>   NULL, '2', '7', 'Large Format' )
>
> INSERT INTO `nested_table` (`id`,
>   `lft`, `rgt`, `category`) VALUES(
>   NULL, '1', '8', 'Books' )
>
> INSERT INTO `nested_table` (`id`,
>   `lft`, `rgt`, `category`) VALUES(
>   NULL, '1', '10', 'CD\'s' )
>
> INSERT INTO `nested_table` (`id`,
>   `lft`, `rgt`, `category`) VALUES(
>   NULL, '10', '13', 'Vintage' )
>
> INSERT INTO `nested_table` (`id`,
>   `lft`, `rgt`, `category`) VALUES(
>   NULL, '1', '14', 'Magazines' )
>
> INSERT INTO `nested_table` (`id`,
>   `lft`, `rgt`, `category`) VALUES(
>   NULL, '0', '15', 'ROOT' )

As you can see, there are multiple rows sharing the lft value of "1" same goes for "2"  In a nested-set, the values for left and right must be unique.  Here is an example of how to manually number the left and right ID's in a nested set:

[image: How to number nested sets]

Image Credit: Gijs Van Tulder, [ref article](https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/)

Comment: I could be wrong but going the other way round means that you must re-index the IDs. otherwise it may not be possible. is that going to cause an issue?

Comment: No, re-indexing the source id's is fine.  That's what I'm doing above.  However, id's don't have anything to do with lft, rgt columns in a nested set.  lft != a row id. I could keep the old ID's if I wanted and it should not make a difference.

Comment: Nice - thanks for coming back with an update...

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to accomplish, however, my ajacency tables are gigantic (16,000 rows), and I am running into an error "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted...on line 74" when running the script (despite php.ini memory values being maxed out). Any idea how I might be able to circumvent this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Right off the top of my head, break your source data into smaller chunks. Only do 1000 rows at a time or something like that.  To speed things up on the mysql end, remove any indexes besides the primary key from the target table. Writing to a table with an index is expensive.  Add indexes to columns in the source table. Reading a table with indexes is fast.  Re-add indexes to the destination table when done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found an answer online and updated the question on this page to show others how it is done.

### UPDATE - PROBLEM SOLVED

First off, I had mistakenly believed that the source table (the one in adjacent-lists format) needed to be altered to include a source node.  This is not the case.  Secondly, I [found a class](http://gen5.info/q/2008/11/04/nested-sets-php-verb-objects-and-noun-objects/) via BING that does the trick.  I've altered it for PHP5 and converted the original author's mysql related bits to basic PHP.  He was using some DB class.  You can convert them to your own database abstraction class later if you want.

Obviously, if your "source table" has other columns that you want to move to the nested set table, you will have to adjust the write method in the class below.

Hopefully this will save someone else from the same problems in the future.

```
<?php

/**


--
-- Table structure for table `adjacent_table`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `adjacent_table`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adjacent_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `father_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `adjacent_table`
--

INSERT INTO `adjacent_table` (`id`, `father_id`, `category`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'Books'),
(2, 0, 'CD''s'),
(3, 0, 'Magazines'),
(4, 1, 'Hard Cover'),
(5, 1, 'Large Format'),
(6, 3, 'Vintage');

--
-- Table structure for table `nested_table`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nested_table`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nested_table` (
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rgt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lft`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rgt` (`rgt`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

*/

    /**
     * @class   tree_transformer
     * @author  Paul Houle, Matthew Toledo
     * @created 2008-11-04
     * @url     http://gen5.info/q/2008/11/04/nested-sets-php-verb-objects-and-noun-objects/
     */
    class tree_transformer 
    {

        private $i_count;
        private $a_link;

        public function __construct($a_link) 
        {
            if(!is_array($a_link)) throw new Exception("First parameter should be an array. Instead, it was type '".gettype($a_link)."'");
            $this->i_count = 1;
            $this->a_link= $a_link;
        }

        public function traverse($i_id) 
        {
            $i_lft = $this->i_count;
            $this->i_count++;

            $a_kid = $this->get_children($i_id);
            if ($a_kid) 
            {
                foreach($a_kid as $a_child) 
                {
                    $this->traverse($a_child);
                }
            }
            $i_rgt=$this->i_count;
            $this->i_count++;
            $this->write($i_lft,$i_rgt,$i_id);
        }   

        private function get_children($i_id) 
        {
            return $this->a_link[$i_id];
        }

        private function write($i_lft,$i_rgt,$i_id) 
        {

            // fetch the source column
            $s_query = "SELECT * FROM `adjacent_table` WHERE `id`  = '".$i_id."'";
            if (!$i_result = mysql_query($s_query))
            {
                echo "<pre>$s_query</pre>\n";
                throw new Exception(mysql_error());  
            }
            $a_source = array();
            if (mysql_num_rows($i_result))
            {
                $a_source = mysql_fetch_assoc($i_result);
            }

            // root node?  label it unless already labeled in source table
            if (1 == $i_lft && empty($a_source['category']))
            {
                $a_source['category'] = 'ROOT';
            }

            // insert into the new nested tree table
            // use mysql_real_escape_string because one value "CD's"  has a single '
            $s_query = "
                INSERT INTO `nested_table`
                (`id`,`lft`,`rgt`,`category`)
                VALUES (
                    '".$i_id."',
                    '".$i_lft."',
                    '".$i_rgt."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($a_source['category'])."'
                )
            ";
            if (!$i_result = mysql_query($s_query))
            {
                echo "<pre>$s_query</pre>\n";
                throw new Exception(mysql_error());  
            }
            else
            {
                // success:  provide feedback
                echo "<p>$s_query</p>\n";
            }
        }
    }

    mysql_connect('localhost','USER','PASSWORD') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('DATABASE') or die(mysql_error());

    // build a complete copy of the adjacency table in ram
    $s_query = "SELECT `id`,`father_id` FROM `adjacent_table`";
    $i_result = mysql_query($s_query);
    $a_rows = array();
    while ($a_rows[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($i_result));
    $a_link = array();
    foreach($a_rows as $a_row) 
    {
        $i_father_id = $a_row['father_id'];
        $i_child_id = $a_row['id'];
        if (!array_key_exists($i_father_id,$a_link)) 
        {
            $a_link[$i_father_id]=array();
        }
        $a_link[$i_father_id][]=$i_child_id;
    }

    $o_tree_transformer = new tree_transformer($a_link);
    $o_tree_transformer->traverse(0);

?>
```

Here is the output:

> INSERT INTO `nested_table`
>   (`id`,`lft`,`rgt`,`category`) VALUES (
>   '4', '3', '4', 'Hard Cover' )
>
> INSERT INTO `nested_table`
>   (`id`,`lft`,`rgt`,`category`) VALUES (
>   '5', '5', '6', 'Large Format' )
>
> INSERT INTO `nested_table`
>   (`id`,`lft`,`rgt`,`category`) VALUES (
>   '1', '2', '7', 'Books' )
>
> INSERT INTO `nested_table`
>   (`id`,`lft`,`rgt`,`category`) VALUES (
>   '2', '8', '9', 'CD\'s' )
>
> INSERT INTO `nested_table`
>   (`id`,`lft`,`rgt`,`category`) VALUES (
>   '6', '11', '12', 'Vintage' )
>
> INSERT INTO `nested_table`
>   (`id`,`lft`,`rgt`,`category`) VALUES (
>   '3', '10', '13', 'Magazines' )
>
> INSERT INTO `nested_table`
>   (`id`,`lft`,`rgt`,`category`) VALUES (
>   '0', '1', '14', 'ROOT' )

Comment: although you couldn't use procedures, but this code takes a lot of time when the data-set is big. A simple procedure on DB could do the work in a second. take a look at this http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/89051/41481

Comment: @azerafati I created an algorithm very similar to the one in this answer. My experience was that this algorithm was much faster (few seconds) compared to your SQL procedure which I aborted after an hour. I had about 2500 rows to process

Comment: @fishbone, ehh you mean the SQL procedure was slow? I'm still using it without nay problem at all.  I'll be very happy to see your algorithm, any link?

Answer (score 1):

Bash converting:

```
# SQL command to fetch necessary fields, output it to text archive "tree"
SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM projects;

# Make a list "id|parentid|name" and sort by name
cat tree |
  cut -d "|" -f 2-4 |
  sed 's/^ *//;s/ *| */|/g' |
  sort -t "|" -k 3,3 > list

# Creates the parenthood chain on second field
while IFS="|" read i p o
do
  l=$p
  while [[ "$p" != "NULL" ]]
  do
    p=$(grep -w "^$p" list | cut -d "|" -f 2)
    l="$l,$p"
  done
  echo "$i|$l|$o"
done < list > listpar

# Creates left and right on 4th and 5th fields for interaction 0
let left=0
while IFS="|" read i l o
do
  let dif=$(grep "\b$i,NULL|" listpar | wc -l)*2+1
  let right=++left+dif
  echo "$i|$l|$o|$left|$right"
  let left=right
done <<< "$(grep "|NULL|" listpar)" > i0

# The same for following interactions
n=0
while [ -s i$n ]
do
  while IFS="|" read i l nil left nil
  do
    grep "|$i,$l|" listpar |
    while IFS="|" read i l o
    do
      let dif=$(grep "\b$i,$l|" listpar | wc -l)*2+1
      let right=++left+dif
      echo "$i|$l|$o|$left|$right"
      let left=right
    done
  done < i$n > i$((++n))
done

# Show concatenated
cat i*|sort -t"|" -k 4n

# SQL commands
while IFS="|" read id nil nil left right
do
  echo "UPDATE projects SET lft=$left, rgt=$right WHERE id=$id;"
done <<< "$(cat i*)"
```

Comment: OP stated specifically: "I need a pure PHP solution." how is this an answer?

Comment: This is a very interesting solution, no matter what the OP stated there (his problem's already solved).
Has anyone tried this solution?