# cypher query to update node properties according to nested set algorithm

Tags: graph, neo4j, tree, cypher

I have employee hierarchy data with

```
MATCH (user:Employee)
MATCH (manager:Employee )
MERGE(user)-[rep:REPORTSTO] -> (manager) where user.managerId=manager.userId;
```

I want to add two more properties to each node: left and right. The values are to be populated as per the nested set algorithm ([image in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664517/how-do-you-convert-a-parent-child-adjacency-table-to-a-nested-set-using-php-an))

How can I do this with cypher?

Comment: An advantage of using a graph DB like neo4j is that you can directly operate on a hierarchy, and don't need to use the cumbersome nested set algorithm. Is this a real requirement?

Comment: @cybersam unfortunately we're using a third party visualization tool which only accepts data in relational format. so we compute those left and right values and push it to the tool to extract the required data for any heirarchy